# ASP.NET MVC5 transform image path to another projects url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two MVC projects in my solution. One is used as backend and the other as frontend. The backend manages content for multiple possible replications of the frontend, for example a CMS admin (backend) for multiple virtual shops (frontends).

The problem is that the images I upload are located in the backend project Content folder, so when I access from the frontend, the URL is not valid. What options are there? I read about the virtual path provider, but I guess it might not be a valid approach in a virtual shared hosting ISP.

I think it would be better to map any "Content/ProductImages/*.*" path into the corresponding full URL for the same resource in the backend project, like "http://something.backend/Content/ProductImages/*.*".

Even though I like this solution, a) I don't know how is it implemented, and b) I don't know how to deal with development and production environment (i.e., in dev I use "something.localhost", while in prod I have "something.com" kind of URLs).

Answer (score 0):

from top of my head - you can:

- Use the admin full image URL in the frontend website.
- Upload to cloud service.
- Let Admin access client website and upload files there (which may not be possible in shared environments, but you can contact your hosting company they may have a way to do it)